# Install latest version of number-versioned software like Tomcat using apt-get?

Tags: bash, aptitude

I'm not looking for some nightly releases, I just want the highest version of software available in apt's database. Although a beginner, I managed to pull just a list of basic tomcat installations:

```
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~/$ aptitude search tomcat[0-9]+$
p   tomcat7                         - Servlet and JSP engine                    
i   tomcat8                         - Apache Tomcat 8 - Servlet and JSP engine
```

Same can be done for other programs too, but I have not found any other that would host 2 different versions with otherwise same name. I assume one day `tomcat0` will pop out and I'd rather not edit my installer just to ensure we're up to latest version.

So is there a way to extend my command in such a way that it will find highest if `tomcat[0-9]+` matches which will them be used for `apt-get install`, like this?

```
TOMCAT=getLatestTomcat; # I need your help with this line
read -p "Tomcat server is missing. Install $TOMCAT server automatically?" -n 1 -r
echo 
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
   echo "Ok, installing.";
   apt-get install $TOMCAT
else
   echo "Ok, do it yourself..."
   exit 404;
fi;
```

It would be great if the answer was more generic, as it may be more useful in further applications than the script I'm just doing.

Comment: Side note: `exit 404` is the same as saying `exit 128`. Only 0-255 are valid exit codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `sort` for this. Here is an example:

```
getLatestTomcat() {
  apt-cache search 'tomcat[0-9]+$' | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort --version-sort | tail -n 1
}

tomcat_package=$(getLatestTomcat)
```

Comment: Works thanks. If you ever came here again, could you please tell me what's the `awk` thing doing with the curly braces?

Comment: @TomášZato it's printing the first column.